# What is the time limit for IPMI soft reboot timeout to revert to hard reboot?

Tags: ipmitool, reboot

Using frucontrol you can specify a soft reboot ipmi request with the command

`ipmitool picmg frucontrol 0 2`

Where the "2" at the end indicates a reboot, as opposed to a "0" which indicates a power off.

When you issue the command it will "ask" the OS to perform a reboot and if it's not successful in a certain period of time ipmitool "pulls the plug" and issues a hard reboot. What I'm trying to find is what the timeout is and I can't seem to find that information anywhere.
Also, if there is a way to set that timeout then it would be useful to know. The documentation doesn't seem to cover these aspects so I figured I'd ask. Thanks in advance.